# Features for Support Vector Machine (SVM)

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, svm, svd

I have to classify some texts with support vector machine. In my train file I have 5 different categories. I have to do classify at first with "Bag of Words" feature, after with SVD feature by keeping 90% of the total variance.

I 'm using python and sklearn but I don't know how to create the above SVD feature.

My train set is separated with tab (\t), my texts are in 'Content' column and the categories are in 'Category' column.

Comment: Do [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer) first, then [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) and keep only features responsible for 90% variance. Finally, [SVM](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)

Comment: in TfidfVectorizer i use only stop_words parameters is it ok?
how to use pca?

Answer (score 1):

The high level steps for a tf-idf/PCA/SVM workflow are as follows:

Load data (will be different in your case):

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
categories = ['alt.atheism', 'soc.religion.christian']
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=categories)
train_text = newsgroups_train.data
y = newsgroups_train.target
```

Preprocess features and train classifier:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.svm import SVC

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_text)

pca = PCA(.8)
X = pca.fit_transform(X_tfidf.todense())

clf = SVC(kernel="linear")
clf.fit(X,y)
```

Finally, do the same preprocessing steps for `test` dataset and make predictions.

PS

If you wish, you may combine preprocessing steps into `Pipeline`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
preproc = Pipeline([('tfidf',TfidfVectorizer())
                    ,('todense', FunctionTransformer(lambda x: x.todense(), validate=False))
                    ,('pca', PCA(.9))])
X = preproc.fit_transform(train_text)
```

and use it later for dealing with test data as well.

Comment: todense() makes my program too slow, can I use TruncatedSVD instead?

Comment: You can, but in that that case you'll need to adjust for number of components manually, not by specifying the percentage of variance explained.

Comment: Did this help? If so you may think about accepting and upvoting the answer.

Comment: I'm still trying to make it work by using TruncatedSVD that's because I don't accept the answer yet. I 'm going to accept when I find the result I need for my problem.